# Rejected by SLM Monitor canada post api

Tags: api, post

I keep getting error when querying for details from CanadaPost API. I go for about 300 request in foreach and some of them response 200 but most of them 500 with message below:
Code: Server
Error Msg: Rejected by SLM Monitor

If i query single item it always goes well with 200 stutus code.

Answer (score 5):

Canada Post's API by default limits you to 20 requests per minute. After that, it will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<messages xmlns="http://www.canadapost.ca/ws/messages">
<message>
<code>Server</code>
<description>Rejected by SLM Monitor</description></message></messages>
```

You can [request a limit increase](https://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/drc/increaseLimits?execution=e8s1) or throttle your code so that you're below the limit.

Source: https://forums.canadapost.ca/forum/posts/list/29020.page (requires login).